# Regex to match any number of words if any of the words have a specific character

Tags: regex

I have a Python list of several cities and I’m trying to match only those that have certain accented characters. I managed to get a lot of them, but not all (it fails at 'El Fuerte de la Unión' for example.

I also feel that my syntax could be more efficient, I’m adding word and whitespace characters, but there must be a better way. I’m not sure how to construct a search that would take into account that there may or may not be multiple words or spaces before a word with required characters is matched.

This is my syntax:

```
'(\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*[áíúóéó]+.*?\s*\w*)'
```

This is a portion of the list:

```
'Name', 'San Marcos Tecomaxusco', 'Teapa', 'Tatatila', 'Sisal', 'Simojovel de Allende', 'El Fuerte de la Unión', 'Santiago Zoochila', 'Santiago Nuyoó', 'Miahuatlán', 'Santa María Huazolotitlán', 'Santa María Chimalhuacán', 'Santa María Apazco', 'Santa Cruz Ozolotepec', 'San Simón', 'Huixcolotla', 'San Rafael Ixtapalucan', 'San Pedro Mixtepec', 'San Pedro Huilotepec', 'San Miguel Balderas', 'San Mateo Almomoloha', 'San Martín Chalchicuautla', 'Teolocholco', 'San Luis Ayucán', 'San Juan Zitlaltepec', 'San José de las Flores', 'San Jerónimo Xayacatlán', 'San Hipólito', 'San Francisco Oxtotilpan', 'San Cristóbal de las Casas'
```

Here is a link to regex101 with the full list: https://regex101.com/r/6WlY8o/1

Comment: It is possible that `Unión` uses a combining character vs an actual code point. Those are two different characters that *look* like the same character.

Comment: No, I checked, it’s the same character that is in my search string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following regex:

```
'[^']*[áíúóéó][^']*'
```

Regex Explanation:

- `'`: single quote
- `[^']*`: any non-single quote
- `[áíúóéó]`: one accented character
- `[^']*`: any non-single quote
- `'`: single quote

If you don't want to match single quotes, you can add lookarounds:

```
(?<=')[^']*[áíúóéó][^']*(?=')
```

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ouCLe0/1).

Comment: This seems to work, but I’m not sure why. Basically it searches for a quote, followed by any character but the quote, then the required and then anything but the quote till it hits the quote? I’d be grateful if you could explain why this works and something like this doesn’t ˋ'[^.]*[áíúóéó][^.]*'ˋ

Comment: That wouldn't work because in your case the delimiter is the quote, not the dot. What I do here is enforcing the match between two quotes, and that match has to have an accented character. If in the middle there's another quote, it means that the match has to end before, because the quote is our delimiter.